# Element doesn't have inner text in DOM, how to get that value?

Tags: html, dom, playwright

[This is an example of such element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYM8d.png)

How is it possible to get the value `99` during testing?
I'm using playwright and anything like `innerText()` or `textContent()` don't work at all.

```js
await expect(page.locator(element)).toHaveText('99')  //OR
await expect(page.locator(element).innerText()).toBe('99')
```

It's fully logical that these methods should get the value from elements like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGqB5.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the presence of value for this.

```js
await expect(page.locator(element)).toHaveValue('99')
```